# もう治らないと言われた目が見えるようになった。これが奇跡でなくてなんだろう English Translation?

Tags: translation

I found this sentence in a book.

> もう治らないと言われた目が見えるようになった。これが奇跡でなくてなんだろう

It doesn't make sense to me at all.

もう治らないのに、なんで奇跡と呼ぶのでしょうか？

翻訳してください。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> もう治らないのに、なんで奇跡と呼ぶのでしょうか？

いえ、治ったんです。「治らない」と言われたのに、治ったから、「奇跡」と呼んでいるんです。

> ［『もう治らない』と言われた］目が見えるようになった。

「もう治らない」 is what was said by the doctor.
もう治らないと言われた is a relative clause modifying 目.

It literally says: "My eyes, [which the doctor said wouldn't recover], became able to see." i.e. "The doctor said my eyesight would never recover, but I regained my eyesight."